# Missing email notification in Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal

Usually Payment Notification email would be sent to buyer and seller.  For some reason, I do not see this in Paypal Sandbox Notification list of both buyer and seller.  However when login buyer or seller Paypal Sandbox account, the transaction is there but no notification was received.

I checked the setting, the email notification is set by default.
Also when test issuing refund, for some reason, the notification email is sent out (i.e. listed in Notification menu).

Help.  What do I miss and suggestion please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

On the sandbox PayPal doesn't send actual emails out.  Instead, any email that a sandbox account would typically get sent goes to your developer account.

Log in to your account at http://developer.paypal.com, then click to Applications, and then Sandbox Accounts.  Click the little arrow next to an account in there to display extra links, one of which is Notifications.

Click into Notifications to see email notifications that you would typically expect to get at your real email on a live account.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  That was where I checked and there were no notifications.  I also did check the notification setting of the sandbox a/c. Again, seems ok.  I did not get notification on payment being made or received but i did get notification when chg of password or refund.  What do I miss?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested to buy from sandbox buyer account to a live seller account and didn't get any email notification and not found under live seller account. Is that normal because it was sandbox buyer account and should work if both accounts are live?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it needs time to be those notifications visible in the developer console too. We have to wait 5 hours in some cases.